# Conditional rows and/or columns using css (flex, grid)

Tags: css

In my project I have section in form, that can have several fields depending on request result from api. It can display from 1 to 4 fields. According to design system, if there are up to 3 fields, they should be displayed in exactly 1 row, but if there are 4 fields, they should be placed in 2 rows (2 fields per row). I'm wondering if there a smart way without using javascript, to place them in compliance with design system.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ1Gr.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRj7i.png

I've search uncle google and I found few examples of auto placement with css grid, but all of them are placing items in fixed row size which is not that I'm looking for

Comment: Well.. there's a dirty way. The default is: `.container > * {flex: 1 0 0}`. If there are four elements, the first one is: `.container > :nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4){ flex: 0 0 50% }`, the second one is: `.container > :nth-child(2):nth-last-child(3){ flex: 0 0 50% }` and so on. But again this is dirty and smells bad. Adding/removing corresponding class to the container via script is a better way IMHO.

Comment: Update: the shorter and better version for 4 elements: `.container > :nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4),  .container > :nth-child(1):nth-last-child(4) ~ *{ flex: 0 0 50% }` No need to define `flex` property for all individual elements, only first one and all the following.

Comment: I was afraid that I won't be able to not touch js, but it seems so

Comment: Well the second variant seems quite acceptable to me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jared sorry I sent my comment without refreshing page, so didn't notice second option. Looks quite good, and almost fits my needs. There is one more problem. There are different gaps when 3 items, and four items. When 3 - horizontal gap is 24px, when 4 - horizontal 90px and vertical 24px. Using grid & JS I'm able to do so, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do that with flex? gap in flexbox is consistent in both axis, so I would say I need to use margin

Comment: I've tried `> element:nth-last-child(4) ~ element:nth-last-child(2),element:nth-child-child(3)` to select second and third element when there is 4 element available and it seems that I can use it to set margin for these elements. Thanks for your help!